# Understanding Query Plan’s “width”

Tags: postgresql

The Douglas and Douglas PostgreSQL book includes the following EXPLAIN result:

[image]

The first step of the query, the Seq Scan, shows a width of 1917. However the last step of the query, the Sort, has a width of 1911.

Why/how could these values differ?

Comment: There's more stored in the row than is actually being returned to the user. The difference might be the null bitmap.

Comment: Run the query using `explain (analyze, verbose)` then you can see what columns are taken into account which make up the `width`

Answer (score 3):

Every PostgreSQL row version (“tuple”) has a number of system columns and other data that are not displayed by `SELECT *` (see [the documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/storage-page-layout.html#HEAPTUPLEHEADERDATA-TABLE) for details. Among them are

- `xmin` and `xmax`
- extra flags that contain the “hint bits” and the “frozen” flag.
- `ctid`, the tuple's physical address.

These would account 23 bytes, not for four, so you'd have to look at tge source for more. The only of these items that occupies 6 bytes is `ctid`, so maybe that.